# If this UK parliament runs its full term, will the next general election be in December?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament

If this parliament runs its full term, does the fixed term parliament act mean that the next general election will be in December?

Answer (score 5):

No.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-term_Parliaments_Act_2011).

> Under the FTPA, the next general election is automatically scheduled
>   for the first Thursday in May of the fifth year after the previous
>   general election—or the fourth year if the date of the previous
>   election was before the first Thursday in May.